# Как получить имя JPanel в ActionEvent

Tags: java, swing

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть следующая структура(см. скрин). JPanel cards0, cards1... используют CardLayout. Как сделать один общий ActionListener на несколько кнопок? Как получить имя JPanel?

```
btn0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        lbl0.setIcon(images.get(parseInt(e.getActionCommand())));
        CardLayout c1 = (CardLayout) (**cards0**.getLayout());
        c1.show(**cards0**, "Card2");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем уверен в том, что вы хотите сделать. 
Но кнопку можно достать из источника события, далее из названия кнопки достать номер. Так же можно получить ссылку на родительский элемент и на основе этой информации уже что то сделать.

НО, кнопки придется называть соответствующим образом, что бы этот код работал.

```
private static class CustomListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
        //button_<number>
        String name = button.getName();
        String number = name.substring(name.indexOf("_" + 1));

        //card panel
        final JPanel parent = (JPanel) button.getParent();
        final CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) parent.getLayout();
        layout.show(parent, "Card" + number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Нужен был метод getParent() и то, что нужно было привести к (JButton), (JPanel) . С остальным разобрался.